# $(1+\cos x + 2\sin x)\frac{dy}{dx} + (\sin x-2\cos x)y = 5-3\cos x + 4\sin x$ case when $1+\cos x+2\sin x = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of
>   $(1+\cos x +2\sin x)\dfrac{dy}{dx} + (\sin x-2\cos x)y = 5-3\cos x + 4\sin x$

I solved it, with dividing both sides by $(1+\cos x+2\sin x)^2$,
Solution giving $y=4+5\sin x + K(1+\cos x + 2\sin x)$, $K$ being arb const.

The question does not give any domain and range of $x,y$,
So I am worried about the case when $(1+\cos x +2\sin x)=0$,
since there are many instances of $x$ where that holds.

While solution paper do not say anything other than the above solution,
should I also check if a particular solution of $x$ where $1+\cos x + 2\sin x=0$ 
holds in $(\sin x-2\cos x)y = 5-3\cos x + 4\sin x$
and state that solution alongside the solution stated above?

Many thanks in advance.
Chris

Comment: I find the tag juxtaposition of "algebra-precalculus" and "differential-equations" somewhat disconcerting...

Comment: I think it is advisable to go first to tangent of x / 2 to rationalize the question what  will clarify it.

Comment: Those points are singular and do not belong to the domain of the ODE. Solutions can only be defined on the intervals between the roots of that factor. You may be able to continue some solutions, but that continuation is not unique and not a (regular) ODE solution, but a function that is pieced together from ODE solutions.